# Trouble getting a mock to run on an imported function

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following function does not mock when imported from its actual file, but does work when copied into the test file and then referenced directly:

```
const testF = () => {
  return fetch(null, {
    body : JSON.stringify(4)
  })
    .then(res => res.json());
};

exports.testF = testF;
```

In my testing file I have this:

```
global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock');
const targetFile = require("../targetFile.js");

test('testF', async () => {
  await fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(2));

  await targetFile.testF().then(jsonData => {
    expect(jsonData).toEqual(2)
  });
});
```

Also tried setting it this way and restarting the test runner:

```
// package.json
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [ "./setupJest.js" ]
  }


// setupJest.js
global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock');


// seen in jest/terminal
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Request internals)' of null

  225 | 
  226 | const testF = () => {
> 227 |   return fetch(null, {
      |          ^
  228 |     body : JSON.stringify(4)
  229 |   })
  230 |     .then(res => res.json());
```

Anyone know what is wrong and how to get the imported function to use the mocked global.fetch?

Comment: You stringifying "2".. is that even valid JSON?

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(2)); // "2"` I planned to put a more complex object in there, this was just for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by entering the following into the target file:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  fetch = window.fetch;
} else { fetch = global.fetch }

const diffFileFetch = () => {
  return fetch();
};
```

Now fetch is scoped correctly for production/testing.

Then in the test runner file:

```
global.fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('test value'));

test('diffFileFetch', () => {
  targetFile.diffFileFetch()
    .then(data => {
      expect(data).toEqual('test value');
    });
});
```